# Get children only if parent matches in LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm making a big LDAP query.  I want to get a bunch of entries, let's call them Items, and I want to get each Item's SubItem as well (but only if Item matches).

For example, let's say `MyItem` has a field `BirthdayToday`, and its value is `True`, and there are a thousand other Items, but their value for that field is `False`.  Every Item, `MyItem` included, has a SubItem.

I want to get every Item with a birthday today, along with its SubItem.  So my result should return `MyItem` and its SubItem, we'll call it `MySubItem`.

I cannot think of a good way to do this in one query, since LDAP isn't very dynamic.  I could do this in two queries if LDAP would allow me to check the `distinguishedName` field, but it doesn't, it only allows me to see if it the value is present.

Eg, this works: `distinguishedName=*` but this doesn't: `distinguishedName=*word*`.

Anyone know of how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one LDAP search. You would have to search for the parent items that match, and then list their subcontexts, or search them.